# How to mock DynamoDB with Mockito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I got some code that already makes my DynamoDB instance mocked using PowerMockito like that:

```
@Mock
private DynamoDB dynamoDB;
 .....
PowerMockito.whenNew(DynamoDB.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(dynamoDB);
```

Our code coverage plugin doesn't like PowerMockito so he doesn't include these tests in the code coverage.

Due to that, now I need to use Mockito instead of PowerMockito.

I tried the following code below to make my DynamoDB mocked, but it failed:

```
DynamoDB mockedInstance = Mockito.mock(DynamoDB.class);
Mockito.doReturn(mockedInstance).when(carFactorySpy).carFactoryMethod("us-west-2");
```

The DynamoDB is being created like:

```
DynamoDB ddbCon = new DynamoDB(Regions.fromName(region));
```

or -

```
DynamoDB ddbCon = new DynamoDB(Regions.US_WEST_2);
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: there is no raised error. the DynamoDB object is just not being mocked

Comment: what is the mockito version u are using?

Comment: i'm using the last version

Comment: Can you share some of your source code to see how the `DynamoDB` object is declared/instantiated?

Comment: You could also use a mock implementation like - https://github.com/mboudreau/Alternator/

Comment: @codepills i've updated the question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mockito.initMocks()](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.6/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html) or [MockitoJUnitRunner](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object)) annotation to setup mocking for your test. Also, it would be nice to provide with the failure message you are getting.

Comment: I have added links to the documentation. Basically you need to write them somewhere in your test suit as part of the setup.

Answer (score 0):

The details of your implementation are still a little unclear to me but here's a try.

#### If your test subject looks like...

```
private CarFactory carFactory;

public void foo() {
    DynamoDB ddbCon = carFactory.carFactoryMethod("us-west-2"));
    // use ddbCon
}
```

#### Then your unit test could look something like...

```
@Mock
private CarFactory carFactory;

@Test
public void fooShouldUseMockDynamoDb() {
    DynamoDb ddbCon = mock(DynamoDB.class);
    when(carFactory.carFactoryMethod("us-west-2")).thenReturn(ddbCon);
    // stub ddbCon
}
```

FWIW, I also try to avoid PowerMockito but more so because it is slow then code coverage not being captured.